# Wobble effect in android

Tags: android

I am trying to make an application in which I want to use wobble effect. It's same like the AndWobble2 apps. But I am not able to find how it should be exactly done. I found one library named Army Knife Library which is used for J2ME based mobiles. My question is can we use the same library for the adding the wobble effect to images or can we do this in opengl? Does anyone have any links or explanations to see how this is done? Thanks in advance.